# Django: AttributeError form has no attribute 'is_valid'

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue saving comments for a blog app I'm writing in Django. The error is: `AttributeError at /blog/123456/ 'comment' object has no attribute 'is_valid'`

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class comment(models.Model):
    comID = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    postID = models.ForeignKey(post)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.db.models import Count
from blog.models import post, comment
from site.helpers import helpers

def detail(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = comment(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            com = form.save(commit=False)
            com.postID = post_id
            com.comID = helpers.id_generator()
            com.user = request.user.username
            com.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/'+post_id+"/")
    else:
        blog_post = post.objects.get(postID__exact=post_id)
        comments = comment.objects.filter(postID__exact=post_id)
        form = comment()
        context = RequestContext(request, {
            'post': blog_post,
            'comments': comments,
            'form': form,
        })
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', context)
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, from the tutorials/examples I've been looking at, `form` should have the attribute `is_valid()`. Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think `comment` is a form? It is a model object; you imported it from your models module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I feel stupid now. I was under the impression that models create forms. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll go write some forms now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comment` is a Model. `is_valid` method are present in forms. I think what you wnat to do is create a `ModelForm` for comment like this:

```
from django import forms
from blog.models import comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model=comment
```

And use `CommentForm` as IO interface to `comment` class.

You can learn more about [`ModelForm`s at the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Hope this helps!